# PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder generates invalid PKCS10CertificationRequest in org.bouncycastle.pkcs

Tags: android, x509certificate, bouncycastle, pki, jce

I am trying to use Spongy Castle (v1.47) to create a PKCS10 Certification Request. Spongy Castle behaves exactly the same way as Bouncy Castle, but is more suited to port on Android.

The old (depricated) way as described in Beginning Cryptography with Java by David Hook in chapter 6 works just fine:

```
package chapter6;

import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Vector;
import javax.security.auth.x500.X500Principal;
import org.spongycastle.asn1.DEROctetString;
import org.spongycastle.asn1.DERSet;
import org.spongycastle.asn1.pkcs.Attribute;
import org.spongycastle.asn1.pkcs.PKCSObjectIdentifiers;
import org.spongycastle.asn1.x509.GeneralName;
import org.spongycastle.asn1.x509.GeneralNames;
import org.spongycastle.asn1.x509.X509Extension;
import org.spongycastle.asn1.x509.X509Extensions;
import org.spongycastle.jce.PKCS10CertificationRequest;
import org.spongycastle.openssl.PEMWriter;
import org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

/**
 * Generation of a basic PKCS #10 request with an extension.
 */
public class PKCS10ExtensionExample {
  static {
    BouncyCastleProvider prov = new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider();
    Security.addProvider(prov);
  }

  public static PKCS10CertificationRequest generateRequest( KeyPair pair) throws Exception {
    // create a SubjectAlternativeName extension value
    GeneralNames subjectAltName = new GeneralNames(new GeneralName(GeneralName.rfc822Name, "test@test.test"));

    // create the extensions object and add it as an attribute
    Vector oids = new Vector();
    Vector values = new Vector();
    oids.add(X509Extensions.SubjectAlternativeName);
    values.add(new X509Extension(false, new DEROctetString(subjectAltName)));
    X509Extensions extensions = new X509Extensions(oids, values);
    Attribute attribute = new Attribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_extensionRequest, new DERSet(extensions));

    return new PKCS10CertificationRequest(
           "SHA256withRSA",
           new X500Principal("CN=Requested Test Certificate"),
           pair.getPublic(),
           new DERSet(attribute),
           pair.getPrivate());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // create the keys
    KeyPairGenerator kpGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "SC");
    kpGen.initialize(1024, Utils.createFixedRandom());
    KeyPair pair = kpGen.generateKeyPair();
    PKCS10CertificationRequest request = generateRequest(pair);
    PEMWriter pemWrt = new PEMWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
    pemWrt.writeObject(request);
    pemWrt.close();
  }
}
```

The small java program prints out the following:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
MIIBkDCB+gIBADAlMSMwIQYDVQQDExpSZXF1ZXN0ZWQgVGVzdCBDZXJ0aWZpY2F0
ZTCBnzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOBjQAwgYkCgYEAm38mHcNo+YDhe1/XHRa1Cifj
EUwH6SQfqKQcY0sO4gGTVL/U5kBx/y0gIptrnGgUYgfwqptWoKHIqd4PGAuzHfwI
QrTfnYtLnN3dBdnOx/1mZuJ/fCD48H45sTVCcXbypxdwns2PZwgh1rt+jb7TJQii
5TteCLvzzb7FVb/Oc6MCAwEAAaAsMCoGCSqGSIb3DQEJDjEdMBswGQYDVR0RBBIw
EIEOdGVzdEB0ZXN0LnRlc3QwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADgYEAJexpAYF6RvbYGiNS
kyaF1H8TpDOHaAuIvS4G2Kqw9xXJHYEDiNsQxMc4gWdx6ZNDzc1JYqFBaEV+c/zt
pRPLTRxTi841tLBUAzX7eFQ5EtLwJrKLlHCMXxg3DwcrPjRwidcE87Nl/sOyeT4K
btCXzqpLtklJi/giBl/4L+lQunU=
-----END CERTIFICATE REQUEST-----
```

The problem is that in the meanwhile (the book is from 2005) most of this Classes are marked as depricated. The new way of creating certificate signing requests is by using Factory Patterns:

```
package chapter6;

import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.security.KeyPair;
import java.security.KeyPairGenerator;
import java.security.Security;
import java.util.Vector;

import org.spongycastle.asn1.DERPrintableString;
import org.spongycastle.asn1.pkcs.PKCSObjectIdentifiers;
import org.spongycastle.asn1.x500.X500Name;
import org.spongycastle.asn1.x509.ExtendedKeyUsage;
import org.spongycastle.asn1.x509.KeyPurposeId;
import org.spongycastle.asn1.x509.KeyUsage;
import org.spongycastle.asn1.x509.SubjectPublicKeyInfo;
import org.spongycastle.asn1.x509.X509Extension;
import org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
import org.spongycastle.openssl.PEMWriter;
import org.spongycastle.operator.ContentSigner;
import org.spongycastle.operator.ContentVerifierProvider;
import org.spongycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentSignerBuilder;
import org.spongycastle.operator.jcajce.JcaContentVerifierProviderBuilder;
import org.spongycastle.pkcs.PKCS10CertificationRequest;
import org.spongycastle.pkcs.PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder;

/**
 * Generation of a basic PKCS #10 request with an extension.
 */
public class PKCS10ExtensionExampleNew {
  static {
    BouncyCastleProvider prov = new org.spongycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider();
    Security.addProvider(prov);
  }

  public static PKCS10CertificationRequest generateRequest(KeyPair pair) throws Exception {
    SubjectPublicKeyInfo publicKeyInfo = SubjectPublicKeyInfo.getInstance(pair.getPublic().getEncoded());
    X500Name subject = new X500Name("CN=Requested Test Certificate");
    PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder certificationRequestBuilder = new PKCS10CertificationRequestBuilder(subject, publicKeyInfo);

    certificationRequestBuilder.addAttribute(X509Extension.keyUsage, 
        new KeyUsage(KeyUsage.digitalSignature | KeyUsage.keyEncipherment | KeyUsage.dataEncipherment | KeyUsage.keyAgreement));

    Vector<KeyPurposeId> ekUsages = new Vector<KeyPurposeId>();
    ekUsages.add(KeyPurposeId.id_kp_clientAuth);
    ekUsages.add(KeyPurposeId.id_kp_serverAuth);
    certificationRequestBuilder.addAttribute(X509Extension.extendedKeyUsage, new ExtendedKeyUsage(ekUsages));

    JcaContentSignerBuilder contentSignerBuilder = new JcaContentSignerBuilder("SHA1WithRSAEncryption");
    contentSignerBuilder.setProvider("SC");
    ContentSigner contentSigner = contentSignerBuilder.build(pair.getPrivate());

    DERPrintableString password = new DERPrintableString("secret123");
    certificationRequestBuilder.addAttribute(PKCSObjectIdentifiers.pkcs_9_at_challengePassword, password);

    PKCS10CertificationRequest certificationRequest = certificationRequestBuilder.build(contentSigner);

    JcaContentVerifierProviderBuilder contentVerifierProviderBuilder = new JcaContentVerifierProviderBuilder();
    ContentVerifierProvider contentVerifierProvider = contentVerifierProviderBuilder.build(pair.getPublic());
    System.out.println("isSignatureValid? " + certificationRequest.isSignatureValid(contentVerifierProvider));
    System.out.println(certificationRequest.getSubject());
    return certificationRequest;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // create the keys
    KeyPairGenerator kpGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "SC");
    kpGen.initialize(1024, Utils.createFixedRandom());
    KeyPair pair = kpGen.generateKeyPair();
    PKCS10CertificationRequest request = generateRequest(pair);
    PEMWriter pemWrt = new PEMWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(System.out));
    pemWrt.writeObject(request);
    pemWrt.close();
  }
}
```

The Certificate Request does not get properly build, as it fails on the PEM Generation:

```
isSignatureValid? true
CN=Requested Test Certificate
Exception in thread "main" org.spongycastle.util.io.pem.PemGenerationException: unknown object passed - can't encode.
  at org.spongycastle.openssl.MiscPEMGenerator.createPemObject(MiscPEMGenerator.java:208)
  at org.spongycastle.openssl.MiscPEMGenerator.generate(MiscPEMGenerator.java:333)
  at org.spongycastle.util.io.pem.PemWriter.writeObject(PemWriter.java:76)
  at org.spongycastle.openssl.PEMWriter.writeObject(PEMWriter.java:45)
  at be.boeboe.spongycastle.chapter6.PKCS10ExtensionExampleNew.main(PKCS10ExtensionExampleNew.java:71)
```

Anyone has any idea why the second attempt to create a request failed? I created X509V3Certificate certificates both the old and new way and had no problem there, but putting those differences next to the ones shown here, didn't make me any wiser.

Any help kindly appreciated.

Boeboe

Comment: try searching a bit click [this](https://www.google.se/search?num=100&hl=sv&newwindow=1&safe=off&tbo=d&q=PemGenerationException+unknown+object+passed+-+can%27t+encode&oq=PemGenerationException+unknown+object+passed+-+can%27t+encode&gs_l=serp.3...6313.25524.0.26477.4.4.0.0.0.0.73.224.4.4.0...0.0...1c.1j2.SqW0INNp_c0)

Comment: For future reference, I believe the Certificate Request case was missed when the library was reorganised, but that this has been fixed since. There are beta builds available, or 1.48 should be out within the next two weeks.

Comment: have you found a solution?